Blazor Renderfragment RenderTreeBuilder Parent / Childs
I use
RenderFragment MyRenderFragment() { 
    return builder => { switch (item.Name) { case .... 

to run components and it works great.
Now I want to use this on a parent / childs example but I can't work it out.
For example this one :
<RadzenRadioButtonList @bind-Value=@value TValue="int">
    <Items>
        <RadzenRadioButtonListItem Text="Orders" Value="1" />
        <RadzenRadioButtonListItem Text="Employees" Value="2" />
        <RadzenRadioButtonListItem Text="Customers" Value="3" />
    </Items>
</RadzenRadioButtonList>

I tried this code :
builder.OpenComponent<RadzenRadioButtonList<int>>(0);
builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", value);
builder.AddAttribute(2, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create<T>(this, async (T e) =>
{
    await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(e);
}));
builder.AddAttribute(3, "TValue", typeof(int));
builder.AddAttribute(5, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((builder2) =>
{
    // I tried with foreach and get data from List<> but not work, tried with singledata but this will not work neither.
    builder2.OpenComponent<RadzenRadioButtonListItem<int>>(6);
    builder2.AddAttribute(7, "Text", "Orders");
    builder2.AddAttribute(8, "Value", 1);
    builder2.CloseComponent();
}
builder.CloseComponent();

But it will not work. Anyone who knows how to use this in parent / childs relations?

In the code you show the RadzenRadioButtonListItem components in a Parameter RenderFragment named Items , not ChildContent.
//....
builder.AddAttribute(5, "Items", (RenderFragment)((builder2) =>
{
    // can reset the numbering here as it's a different Render Frame
    builder2.OpenComponent<RadzenRadioButtonListItem<int>>(0);
    builder2.AddAttribute(1, "Text", "Orders");
    builder2.AddAttribute(2, "Value", 1);
    builder2.CloseComponent();
}
/....

You will need a @foreach loop to add the various options.

It works, thanks!
